# mysql_unbuffred_query not working

Tags: php, mysql, json, memory

I have a php file which encodes result retrieved from mysql_query() into json format. The data that I receive is large i.e close to 200,000 tuples where each tuple has close to 10 varchars. Earlier I was getting an Exception like "Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted". Then I searched on the internet and someone had quoted mysql_unbuffered_query is the solution. I have tried it too but again I get the same error.   How can we handle such large data in php?

> Increasing the memory is also not an option since I have a shared
>   hosting account.

Here's the code that I am using for retrieving the results and encoding to json.

```
$result=mysql_unbuffered_query("Some query which gives large data");
$res=array();
if($result)
{
    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows);

}
else
{
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Whats the workaround for such problems?

Comment: One *nasty* solution would be to query for chunks in a loop with `LIMIT`.

Comment: I will search how to do that. but why is it nasty??

Comment: @cobra_fast That's what I was just about to suggest. You could even run a count query before to know how many times to loop through

Comment: So, I think what you are trying to say is that I should use count query to decide how many times I should use limit offset.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is what I was imagining, just add your queries, etc.

```
// Must be zero to get 1st record
$limit = 0;
// Determine how many you want to pull at a time
$offset = 10;
// Run count query to get this value
$total = 10000; // <- number of records needing to be pulled
for ($limit; $limit <= $total; $limit + $offset) {
    // Run query here and pump results into an array
    echo "Total: ".$total."<br>";
    echo "offset: ".$offset."<br>";
    echo "limit: ".$limit."<br>";
}
```

---

**Caution:** Make sure that your total count is evenly divisible by your offset or you'll have missing records, for example:

```
$offset = 19;
$total = 10000;
```

Outputs the last call as:

> Total: 10000
>   offset: 19
>   limit: 9994

---

**Edit:**

Try the following template and see if that helps, when I ran the original answer I gave with `json_encode` and `$limit + $offset` in the `for` loop I got the same memory error, but this next bit worked for me.

```
$offset = 10;
$total = 1000000;
$array = array();
for ($limit = 0; $limit <= $total; $limit++) {
    // Your code here
    $array[$limit] = $offset;
    // Keep the following line
    $limit = ($limit - 1) + $offset;
}
print json_encode($array);
```

Comment: I need a single json encoded value at the client side. I tried your approach but I returned a single json encoded value which again gave me the same error I mentioned.

Comment: You say that "increasing the memory is not an option", is this strict to `php.ini` file access? Have you tried placing `ini_set("memory_limit","12M");` at the top of your script? Just double checking.

Comment: Is there anything in your code that we can modify to become more efficient with memory. For example, your sql select statement, are you selecting all when it is not necessary, etc?

Comment: How are you using this output? If you are just printing to screen have you thought about using GET to set your offset and just keeping each query limited to a specified amount? For example, I have an android application that queries our web host server limited to 10 results, when the user presses next I send the offset value through GET

Comment: Basically, I am calling this php file from a python script. The python script then decodes all the json values and writes them into csv file. Can we return multiple json encoded variables??

Comment: I'm working on something, when I ran my code above using `json_encode` on a very small scale I got the same memory error. Turns out `$limit + $offset` does it.

Comment: I have modified my answer, see if that helps.